# $X \cong \operatorname{Proj} \oplus_n H^0(X, O(n)) $

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $ X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a smooth closed subvariety, and $O(1)$ is the pull-back of the line bundle of $O(1)$ on $\mathbb{P}^n$. Then it is claimed:

> $$X \cong \operatorname{Proj}\left(\bigoplus_n H^0\big(X, O(n)\big)\right)\;.$$

This seems quite plausible for me, but I don't know how to show it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This follows from (EGA, II, 4.5.1, (b)) or [(Stacks, 23.24.11)](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01Q1), since $O(1)$ is ample on $X$.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I am looking for. I cannot voteup because of lack of reputation, sorry about that. Using (Stacks, 23.24.11), one know it is a open immersion, and because $X$ is projective, the morphism is proper, thus closed, which shows the image should be the whole thing-Add this trivial comments :)