# Finite generation of $\bigoplus_{n \ge 0} \Gamma(X, \mathscr{O}(n))$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be a ring, $X$ a proper $A$ scheme, and $\mathscr{L}$ an ample invertible sheaf on $X$.
Then we have that $X \cong \operatorname{Proj} \bigoplus_{n \ge 0} \Gamma(X, \mathscr{L}^{\otimes n})$.
(see, for example, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316296/x-cong-operatornameproj-oplus-n-h0x-on).)

Since $X$ is of finte type over $A$, it seems that $\bigoplus_{n \ge 0} \Gamma(X, \mathscr{L}^{\otimes n})$ (as a $\Gamma(X, \mathscr{O})$-algebra) is finitely generated.
More precisely, if $\mathscr{L}^{\otimes N}$ is very ample, then it seems that $\bigoplus_{n \ge 0} \Gamma(X, \mathscr{L}^{\otimes n})$ is generated by $\bigoplus_{N \gt n \ge 0} \Gamma(X, \mathscr{L}^{\otimes n})$.

How can I show it?

Comment: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B5S

Comment: @LazzaroCampeotti It shows only the finitely generation. I want to know its generator.